# How to understand and resolve the "killed" reason in relation to electron crashes

Tags: electron, crash

I collected information about application crashes through the `render-process-gone` event and found that the `killed` reason far exceeds other reasons.

By [electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-render-process-gone):

> `killed` - Process was sent a SIGTERM or otherwise killed externally

In my understanding, the occurrence of `killed` may be due to the application being forcefully terminated by the task manager or by directly shutting down the system.

I don't understand why "killed" is so much higher than other reasons. Are there any measures to address this? Or are there other scenarios that lead to "killed"?

Below is the authentic crash data we have gathered(`[空值]` means none):

[image]

what i expected:

- Expect some ways to improve it
- I hope to have a good explanation to demonstrate why the number of deaths from "killed" is higher than other causes.